# how to use httpRequest in Jenkinsfile pipeline with basic auth

Tags: jenkins, groovy, httprequest

Does anyone know how to use httpRequest in Jenkinsfile pipeline with basic auth?
I checked in the https://github.com/jenkinsci/http-request-plugin, they support Supports Basic Authentication (see global configuration). But when i implemented in my groovy script, i found the following errors. Can anyone show how to pass the user name and password to the httprequest.

```
def masterDataReplicatorTriggerDeployment() {
milestone 40
VaultUtil vaultUtil = PipelineUtil.getInstance(this).getProdVaultUtil()
def ROUTER_USER
def ROUTER_PASS
def baseurl="http://master-data-replicator.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com"
def sourcetenant="revcdevkp"
def targettenant="revcdevpo"
def copyBCdata="/replicator/v1/businessConfig/"
def response


ROUTER_USER=vaultUtil.readCredential
("secret/landscapes/infrastructure/router").get("router.security.username")
ROUTER_PASS=vaultUtil.readCredential
("secret/landscapes/infrastructure/router").get("router.security.password")
response = httpRequest url: 
baseurl+copyBCdata+sourcetenant+"/"+targettenant,
httpMode: 'POST',
authentication: [Username: ROUTER_USER, Password: ROUTER_PASS]
```

}

org.kohsuke.stapler.NoStaplerConstructorException: There's no @DataBoundConstructor on any constructor of class java.lang.String
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.ClassDescriptor.loadConstructorParamNames(ClassDescriptor.java:247)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.(DescribableModel.java:122)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:380)
    at

```
     def creds = "ROUTER_USER:ROUTER_PASS"
     String auth = creds.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
     httpRequest  consoleLogResponseBody: true,  
         url: baseurl+copyBCdata+sourcetenant+"/"+targettenant,                       
         customHeaders:[[name:'Authorization', value:"Basic ${auth}"]]
```

The new problem: 401 authrization problem.
But i did use the right credential and can visit them.

I know my format of authentication is not correct, do you know which supposed to be the correct way?
Thanks.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 25):

Use the credential plugin [Credential plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) for storing your credentials. Then use the ID in the httpRequest.

```
Example :

New credential

Scope : Global
Username : my_technical_user
Password : *******
ID : my_user_id

httpRequest

httpRequest httpMode: 'POST',
url: "${baseurl}${copyBCdata}${sourcetenant}/${targettenant}",
authentication: 'my_user_id'
```

Or you can inject your username and password on the header directly.

```
def creds = "your_username:your_password"
String auth = creds.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
httpRequest  consoleLogResponseBody: true,  
             url: "your_url",                       
             customHeaders:[[name:'Authorization', value:"Basic ${auth}"]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any other approach to realize visiting the endpoint except for the http request? I hope my username and password stored in the vault instead of the credential id.
Best Regards,

Comment: Thank you very much. But I met a new problem here with credential error.

Comment: 401 means not authorized, probably the application you are trying to call is not using basic authentication. Try to call it with Postman and find which kind of authentication it is using.

Comment: I got "Scripts not permitted to use method java.lang.String getBytes". Any other ideas?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->In-process Script Approval may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this with Groovy.

```
def accessToken = "ACCESS_TOKEN".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
def req = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxxx/something/hosts").openConnection();
req.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + accessToken)
def content = req.getInputStream().getText()
```